# Classical language

Tags: meaning, language-evolution

What are classical languages? How they are different from other languages? Is English is an example of classical language?

Comment: Sorry, this is off-topic.  It is not really a question about English, except to the extent that English happens to be a language.

Comment: I really don't see this as being off-topic. It is asking about the meaning of an English phrase, and the answer hinges on a particular meaning of the word ***classical***. If I had the required reputation, I would cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @Stan Rogers: The question doesn't just ask "what is the meaning of *classical* in *classical language*"?  It asks how classical languages are different from other languages — that is off-topic.  It could be made on-topic by removing that portion.

Comment: I read that as part of the meaning of the word *classical*. One cannot answer the question in any form without exploring the use of the word *classical* as it pertains to tradition and education (that is to say, why Latin and ancient Greek, among others, are *classical* while others are merely *foreign*). It would devolve into an off-topic question if it were a matter of structural linguistic differences between languages, but it has nothing to do with any intrinsic attribute of a language. It's not like the question is "why is English not considered a polysynthetic language?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_language) is a good reference.

> A Classical language should be
>   ancient, it should be an independent
>   tradition that arose mostly on its
>   own, not as an offshoot of another
>   tradition, and it must have a large
>   and extremely rich body of ancient
>   literature

Is English is an example of classical language.

No.

> In the context of traditional European
>   Classical studies, the "Classical
>   Languages" refer to Ancient Greek and
>   Latin. In terms of worldwide cultural
>   importance, Edward Sapir in Language
>   (1921) would extend the list by
>   Chinese, Arabic, and Sanskrit.

However, it also states

Early Modern English (language of KJV Bible and Shakespeare, 16th to 17th c.) is the classical **stage** of English -

> Such a stage is limited in time, and
>   is considered "classical" if it comes
>   to be regarded as a literary "golden
>   age" retrospectively

This means today you would consider the Shakespearean period to be the golden age of the English language.

Comment: @khan: you're welcome - not 'great' really, I only quoted wikipedia ;)